# iteration count display in mapply

Tags: r, mapply

I am using mapply(function,args), for a big dataset. After 100 iterations I need to set a delay for 1 sec. So the question is if it possible to show iteration count or progress bar within mapply (function, args)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but if you switch to using the corresponding functions from `plyr` you can add a progress bar to the function call.

Without you giving us a minimal, reproducible example I'm not going to the effort of finding the exact `plyr` equivalent, but it will be one of the `m*ply` functions:

```
> ls(pos=2,pattern="m.*ply")
[1] "maply" "mdply" "mlply" "m_ply"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the total number of iterations in advance, you *could* just add another argument to `mapply` as an iteration counter. In this example I added `z`. This example makes the command line sleep for 1 second every 3 iterations....

```
mapply( function(x,y,z) { if(z%%3==0){Sys.sleep(1);
    cat(paste0( "Interation " , z , " ...sleeping\n") ) }
    x*y } ,x=1:10,y=1:10,z=1:10)
#Interation 3 ...sleeping
#Interation 6 ...sleeping
#Interation 9 ...sleeping
# [1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100
```

If you need more convincing wrap the statement in `system.time()`. I get a runtime of 3.002 seconds.